# C Programming: Do an operation until the desired result

Tags: c, loops, repeat

I'm really new to programming so please help me.
Here's my algorithm:

```
Enter a number
If the number is greater than 26
Subtract 26 from the number 
Until the number is less than 26
Then display the final result
```

How do I write the code for this?
Thank You!

Comment: Questions asking for someone else to write the code for you is generally not well received around here.

Comment: Have you tried writing some code for it? I believe you can consider each line of your algorithm a single task and find a solution for it. Afterwards you should be able to combine these smaller solutions.

Comment: @Zsw I'm really sorry! It's my first time here. Thanks for letting me know, I'll keep it in mind next time! :)

Comment: @JakobRunge Yeah, but I was stuck  on the "repeating" part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. But next time do put some effort when formulating your question

```
if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
    while (n >= 26) {
        n -= 26;
    }
    printf("%d", n) ;
}
```

Comment: Woah! It worked! Thank youuuu! :)